# How to create automatic deploys to Development, Staging and Production environments in Github and AWS?

Tags: docker, github, devops, amazon-ecs, github-actions

I'm trying to implement multiple environments for the product my team is building:

1 - A Production Env running a Dockerized App on Amazon ECS. 
2 - A Staging Env running a Dockerized App on Amazon ECS. 
3 - A Development Env on which the Team works on new Features/hotfixes/bugs.

For instance, the Dockerized App should be published to Production when a new tag is released to the main branch. For Staging when a new merge is made on the main branch.

I know we can implement this using Git Flow and Github Actions.
Unfortunately, I could not find any tutorial teaching how to do this automatically and deploy the Docker Containers to the Amazon ECS.

Thank you, folks!

[EDIT]

Have found a tutorial from AWS

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/containers/create-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-amazon-ecs-with-github-actions-and-aws-codebuild-tests/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andre', [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html) is the closest I can think of. Note it uses CodeCommit instead of GitHub but you could easily modify the workflow suggested to use the latter easily.

In general pay attention to the `imagedefinitions.json` file is created and used. Basically the idea is that you use a template for the task definition with a placeholder for the image name and more specifically for the tag. These are generated on the fly when a build occurs and the values are saved in the `imagedefinitions.json` file which is used to replace the placeholder in the task def template.

[UPDATE] as an alternative, if you are getting started with ECS, my suggestion would be to use something like [AWS Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/) that allows you to do all that without you to have to create all the infrastructure on your own. These two blog posts are a good starting point for getting an idea on [how the basics work](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-aws-copilot/) and how you can [add a pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/automatically-deploying-your-container-application-with-aws-copilot/).